# Hazelcast management center - Membres unable to communicate

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching, hazelcast

I have this config to connect:

```
config.getManagementCenterConfig().setEnabled(true);
config.getManagementCenterConfig().setUrl("http://localhost:8096/hazelcast-mancenter");
```

Error on management center console :

```
2019-05-29 12:44:27 [qtp873415566-15] WARN  org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel - /hazelcast-mancenter/collector.do
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is com.hazelcast.webmonitor.model.DeserializationException: nodeState field is null
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:865)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1655)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:208)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:347)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:263)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1634)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:533)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1317)
```

Error on Client springboot app console:

```
2019-05-29 12:54:27.059  INFO [-,,,] 12068 --- [           main] c.h.i.m.ManagementCenterService          : [10.1.204.138]:5701 [dev] [3.7.7] Hazelcast will connect to Hazelcast Management Center on address: 
http://localhost:8096/hazelcast-mancenter
2019-05-29 12:54:27.090  INFO [-,,,] 12068 --- [           main] com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService      : [10.1.204.138]:5701 [dev] [3.7.7] [10.1.204.138]:5701 is STARTED
2019-05-29 12:54:27.090  INFO [-,,,] 12068 --- [MC.State.Sender] c.h.i.p.impl.PartitionStateManager       : [10.1.204.138]:5701 [dev] [3.7.7] Initializing cluster partition table arrangement...
2019-05-29 12:54:27.115  INFO [-,,,] 12068 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'hazelcastInstance' of type [com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceProxy] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-05-29 12:54:27.197  INFO [-,,,] 12068 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'cacheManager' of type [com.hazelcast.spring.cache.HazelcastCacheManager] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-05-29 12:54:27.205  INFO [-,,,] 12068 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'cacheAutoConfigurationValidator' of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheAutoConfiguration$CacheManagerValidator] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-05-29 12:54:27.292  INFO [-,,,] 12068 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a3818d32] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-05-29 12:54:27.342  INFO [-,,,] 12068 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.feign.TraceFeignClientAutoConfiguration$FeignBeanPostProcessorConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.feign.TraceFeignClientAutoConfiguration$FeignBeanPostProcessorConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c6f962fb] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-05-29 12:54:27.385  INFO [-,,,] 12068 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.async.AsyncDefaultAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.async.AsyncDefaultAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6f4b3654] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-05-29 12:54:28.645  INFO [-,,,] 12068 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8090 (http)
2019-05-29 12:54:28.667  INFO [-,,,] 12068 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-05-29 12:54:28.669  INFO [-,,,] 12068 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.15
2019-05-29 12:54:28.799  WARN [-,,,] 12068 --- [MulticastThread] c.h.i.cluster.impl.MulticastService      : [10.1.204.138]:5701 [dev] [3.7.7] Received a JoinRequest with a different packet version! This -> 4, Incoming -> -84, Sender -> /10.1.204.123
2019-05-29 12:54:29.260  INFO [-,,,] 12068 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-05-29 12:54:29.260  INFO [-,,,] 12068 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 12542 ms
2019-05-29 12:54:30.158  WARN [-,,,] 12068 --- [MC.State.Sender] c.h.i.m.ManagementCenterService          : [10.1.204.138]:5701 [dev] [3.7.7] Failed to send response, responseCode:405 url:http://localhost:8096/hazelcast-mancenter/collector.do
```

I don't see any configuration to be made to set the nodeStatus as described in errorstack trace.

Kindly let know what config to be made. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please specify which version of Hazelcast IMDG and Management Center you are using? It seems you're using IMDG version 3.7.7, can you confirm?

Comment: Yes, for IMDG its 3.7.7 and MC its 3.11 -  is that causing issue?  Also, I have limitation from organization that I cannot upgrade IMDG.

Comment: MC 3.11 doesn't support IMDG 3.7.7. It only supports 3.10.x and 3.11.x. If you're stuck with IMDG 3.7.7, you can only use the Management Center that is shipped in the IMDG 3.7.7 package, which is also version 3.7.7. You can download the IMDG 3.7.7 distribution which includes Management Center 3.7.7 from [here](https://download.hazelcast.com/download.jsp?version=hazelcast-3.7.7&p=)

Answer (score 0):

As stated by @emre in comments, there is official text about it:

> ... the Management Center is compatible with Hazelcast IMDG cluster members having the same or the previous minor version. For example, Hazelcast Management Center version 3.12.x works with Hazelcast IMDG cluster members having version 3.11.x or 3.12.x.

from [Hazelcast Management Center Documentation](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/management-center/latest/manual/html/#downloading-management-center).

The Exception message (`DeserializationException: nodeState field is null`) is not really helpful to realize that.
The same happend to me, I was using Spring boot parent in version `1.5.9.RELEASE` and therefore it had old the dependency of hazelcast (`3.7.8`). You can always check for versions of spring autoconfigured dependencies in `spring-boot-dependencies` projects's `pom.xml` file. There you can see hazelcast version in properties section defined like this:

`<hazelcast.version>3.7.8</hazelcast.version>`

You can

- change the `spring-boot-starter-parent` version to newer (e.g. `2.2.0.RELEASE`) and the issue should dissapear or
- overwrite only the properties in your own `pom.xml` with newer hazelcast version.